# Problema ejecución SQL

Tags: php, mysqli

Simplifico más todavía.

```
<?php
// Conectando, seleccionando la base de datos
$link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', 'entrar')
    or die('No se pudo conectar: ' . mysql_error());
echo 'Connected successfully';
mysql_select_db('proyecto') or die('No se pudo seleccionar la base de datos');

// Realizar una consulta MySQL
$query = 'SELECT * FROM usuario';
$result = mysql_query($query) or die('Consulta fallida: ' .     mysql_error());

// Imprimir los resultados en HTML
echo "<table>\n";
while ($line = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
echo "\t<tr>\n";
foreach ($line as $col_value) {
    echo "\t\t<td>$col_value</td>\n";
}
echo "\t</tr>\n";
}
echo "</table>\n";

// Liberar resultados
mysql_free_result($result);

// Cerrar la conexión
mysql_close($link);
?>
```

Este Escript, el cual es copiado directo de http://php.net/manual/es/mysql.examples-basic.php pero con los credenciales de mi bd devuelve esto.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Sin resulado alguno ni nada, lo mismo que pasaba antes, no me muestra las consultas de mysql pero si me conecta con ella y no sé que hacer.

Comment: Tu consulta es `SELECT 1 FROM dual`. Sinceramente, no creo que un campo de una base de datos se pueda llamar 1. Donde pone 1 tendrías que indicar el campo que quieres recuperar.

Comment: También he probado por ejemplo con select * from usuario   donde usuario es una tabla de la base de datos

Comment: ¿Y usando Select * from usuario no te devuelve nada?

Comment: Para casos que no te sale algo como por ejemplo problemas de base de datos, etc. Te recomendaría que utilices el log de tu apache. Ahí te va a mostrar el error que te esta saliendo.

Comment: Hola Josego. Esto hubiera sido más apropiado como comentario que como respuesta.

Comment: Ok. Y que hago?? Borró esta respuesta y pongo comentario? O como de hace en este caso

Comment: Así mismo, tal como lo dijistes. ¡Gracias josego!

Comment: Para casos que no te sale algo como por ejemplo problemas de base de datos, etc. Te recomendaría que utilices el log de tu apache. Ahí te va a mostrar el error que te esta saliendo.

Comment: Puse como comentario. Ahora quiero borrar la respuesta pero no me deja. No se si la versión móvil no permite. Mañana voy a ver en mi PC. Gracias por la sugerencia

Answer (score 2):

Veo el fallo desde tu `conexion`. `$mysqli` deberia ser tu conexión `$enlace`. También has puesto `connect_errno` en vez de `connect_error`

En primer lugar debes modificar:

```
$enlace = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "entrar", "Proyecto");

/* Debes cambiar $mysqli por $enlace */
if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
   //^^^^^^ 
printf("Falló la conexión: %s\n", $mysqli->connect_error);
                                 //^^^^^^ 
exit();
}
```

Ejemplo modificado de la conexión:

```
$enlace = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "entrar", "Proyecto");

if ($enlace->connect_error) {       
   printf("Falló la conexión: %s\n", $enlace->connect_error);
   exit();
}
```

También veo un fallo cuando quieres ejecutar tu sentencia, debería ser tu conexión, y el `1` lo cambiaría por `*` como ya te han mencionado:

```
$resultado = $mysqli->query("SELECT 1 FROM dual");
             ^^^^^^

//Modificado.
$resultado = $enlace->query("SELECT * FROM dual");
```